# Is it safe to use Google URL Shortener (Goo.gl) to redirect javascript?

Tags: javascript, script-tag, google-url-shortener, goo.gl

I'm doing a code and was wondering if it is safe to use for Goo.gl redirecioar for the right script. Exemple:

```
   <script src="http://goo.gl/v7BGHa" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the http://goo.gl/v7BGHa redirects to a file in Google Drive.

```
https://googledrive.com/host/0B31D-5Qfz3T-VmR3WFpNaHdyaU0/redirectMobile.js
```

**Is safe to do so?**

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Short URLs are convenient for length restrained environments, such as twitter. They don't serve a purpose otherwise.

Comment: I wanted to leave the URL of the script shorter and beautiful. But you think bad do this?

Comment: It creates another request. You have no guarantee when the link will stop working. No human will read your source, and even if they do no one will mind a long resource URL.

Comment: I would be hesitant to do that.  For one, if you had multiple script tags and needed to remove one of them, it would be a pain finding which one was which.  Furthermore, this relies on the goo.gl service to redirect you to the specific page.  If that service terminates in the future, then your script will need to be altered.

Comment: understand, ok, thank you @FritsvanCampen ^_^

Comment: @thtsigma Ie I can use but not guaranteed to el will redirect? And if in the future the Goo.gl is closed (something I think will not happen) I'll lose him?

Comment: I am just saying that is something goes wrong with the shortener service that you are using (it goes offline, gets shutdown, someone reports your link as spam and it gets taken down), you'd have to go back and recreate the link.  It seems to me, that it would be silly to use a shortener for scripts.

Comment: Well, it's Google, I trust him, I think there are many links on the web that are shortened it. google would be dumb not to close or leave standing or something.

Comment: I trust Google, just want to know if there is any risk of not redirect to the script.